# how to make notification in laravel?

Tags: laravel, notifications

For example:

-In one department, all staff using Laravel Excel. Someone is updating data in the excel, I want notification to appear and notify all staff that using the excel.

Comment: How do you want to notify the staff? How are you handling Excel data updates? You need to give us more information? Are you using a package?

Comment: Tq for the question. Its more likely facebook notification. I want more like appear in history of the updates. Notification maybe like pop up message.